# ToggleClass() on user generated element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I am developing a to-do list. I want to toggle the class of a HTML list-element, that represents a to-do. The list-element is generated by the user after the page has been loaded. The ToggleClass-function I have now doesn't work. I am able to catch the dblclick event in the console, but the class does not toggle.

The JavaScript/Jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("dblclick", ["li"], setStatus); 
    console.log("Call setStatus");
});
```

And the setStatus function:

```
setStatus = function (){ 
    console.log("Double clicked on the li");
    $(this).toggleClass("done");
};
```

The HTML

```
 <body>
        <div id ="todoList">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <input type ="text" id ="todoText"/>
        <button id ="addTodoButton">Add!</button>
    </body>
```

The CSS-class

```
.done{
    color: #006600;
}
```

Comment: Per the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/), `selector` is a string not an array. Remove the brackets `[...]`...

Comment: In doc, `[, selector ]` means optional :) Using `["li"]`, you are passing it as event data, and so `this` inside handler refers to `document`, and then you were toggling class on document (which has no meaning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("dblclick", "li", setStatus); 
    console.log("Call setStatus");
});
```

Remove `[]` from `["li"]`, it is not a valid selector, your code fired the callback so showed the message in console.